# compare from date is less than to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, jquery-validate

Hai i am developing application django where in i want to validate fromdate is less than todate.I am using the following code but it is not working

forms.py

class SearchFilterForm(Form):

```
fromdate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
todate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
```

javascript:

```
function comparedate(){
        var fromdate = document.getElementById("id_fromdate");
        var todate = document.getElementById("id_todate");
        if(fromdate<todate){
            alert("Start date should be less than end date");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am getting the input from date picker and the format is yy-mm-dd.The above code is not giving any error in console but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("id_fromdate")` you are retrieving the node. What you need is the value

```
var fromdate = document.getElementById("id_fromdate").value;
var todate = document.getElementById("id_todate").value;
```

Then, you need to compare the dates, not just the string that `.value` would retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fromdate = document.getElementById("id_fromdate").value;
var todate = document.getElementById("id_todate").value;
```

You need to convert date value string date object then you can compare two date object

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

```
Ex. var d1 = new Date();

var d2 = new Date();
if(+d1>+d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (Date.parse(fromDate) > Date.parse(toDate)) {
alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!")
return false;
}
```